# Facebook for WordPress plugin unable to submit Opengraph Action

Tags: wordpress, action, facebook-opengraph

I try to follow the Instructions [here](https://developers.facebook.com/wordpress/) but I also consulted [this](http://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/facebook-plugin-for-wordpress-guide/). I was able to install the plugin, create my Facebook app, get the namespace, icon etc. even a test post worked, but when I click "submit", I get a dialog box that says this:

> Built-in Action Types require that you provide instructions for using your app's Open Graph integration as your Open Graph Test User in a functioning test environment. Failure to provide a functioning test environment will result in rejection of your Action Type.

I've tried typing in the box, but when I click continue I just get this box again. I wanted to setup auto syncing and ditch Networked Blogs, but maybe I should have stayed with a working solution, given this has gone far from smoothly. How do I get the publish article action submitted and approved?

Comment: I don't know about a bounty, that seems like a new feature of Stackoverflow to me. I did document my difficulties further. And I will post some more screenshots of less than enlightening messages I currently get regarding the Facebook App I had to create to use the plugin. http://blog.muschamp.ca/2012/09/09/installed-the-facebook-for-wordpress-plugin/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the Facebook for WordPress plugin to work, but I didn't find it actually made my blog better. It seemed to run slow, unexpectedly stopped working at times, and did not result in increased traffic. If you want to share your posts to Facebook and you can stand clicking the button yourself after you hit publish, I recommend the Professional Share plugin. If you want related posts, I recommend the Yet Another Related Post Plugin.

The Facebook for WordPress plugin and JetPack are just too big, they have too much cruft, they are not worth running in my opinion and I've been using WordPress since 2005. Just because a big corporation makes an official plugin, doesn't mean it is the best.